# R: putting elements in list

Tags: r, list, vector

Total R noob here.

I am having difficulty creating a list of stock tickers.

Here's the situation:

I've created a dataframe of tickers pulled in from Quandl's API.

```
x1<-Quandl.datatable('SHARADAR/SF1',paginate=TRUE, 
                 qopts.columns=c('ticker'))
```

I then try to put this dataframe into a list.

```
x2<-as.list(x1)
```

So that I can then use the API to pull data for all the tickers in the list.

```
x3<-Quandl.datatable('SHARADAR/SF1',paginate=TRUE, 
                 qopts.columns=c('ticker','dimension','datekey','revenue'),
                 dimension='ART', calendardate='2015-12-31',ticker=c(x2))
```

But, alas, this doesn't work.

Compare this, however, with when I pull specific tickers:

```
Quandl.datatable('SHARADAR/SF1', ticker=c('AAPL', 'TSLA'))
z = list('AAPL','TSLA')
```

The code behaves itself:

```
x3<-Quandl.datatable('SHARADAR/SF1',paginate=TRUE, 
                 qopts.columns=c('ticker','dimension','datekey','revenue'),
                 dimension='ART', calendardate='2015-12-31',ticker=z)
```

This is because each ticker is its own component in the list(z):

[[1]]
[1] "AAPL"

[[2]]
[1] "TSLA"

Whereas for x2 all the tickers are stored as a single list component:

[1] "AAPL", "TSLA", etc.

Therefore I'd be swell if I could find a way to convert vector x2 into a list where each element is it's own component.

Thank a bunch (and for your patience as well!)

Comment: Try `as.list(1:5000)` - `1:5000` creates a numeric vector of sequence from 1 to 5000. `list(...)` then assigns the numeric vector you just created as the first element of a new list.

Comment: What happens when you try my original suggestion, x2 = sapply(x1, list)?

Comment: It's still a list of length 1.  Is this related to the length of a dataframe being equal to the number of columns, not elements?

Comment: Questions should have examples that people can replicate. I don't have Quandl installed, so it's very difficult to help out. Can you show the output of str(x1)? If x1 is a list of length 1, then try sapply(x1[[1]], list)

Comment: Thank you very much regardless!  Yes, str(x1) is a length of 1 and when I use sapply(x1[[1[[,list), it just kicks back:                               
'dataframe': 5375 obs. of 1 variable: $ ticker: chr "A" "AA" "AAAP" ...

Comment: `dput` is great for copy/pasteable R objects. `dput(droplevels(head(x1)))` will give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 6 rows of `x1`. The `droplevels()` is only needed if you have factors with a lot of levels.

Comment: My best guess is that `x1` is a one column data frame. Because a `data.frame` really is a `list` under the hood, `as.list()` just gives you a list of columns. I think you just want `as.list(x1$your_column_name)`, where `your_column_name` is `ticker` or whatever the name of the column is.

Comment: That was exactly it @Gregor  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it's solved! Next time, please *show* sample data, and we can get there much quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
x = sapply(1:5000, list)
```

The length is 5000:

```
length(x)
[1] 5000
```

All elements are integers:

```
all(sapply(x, is.integer) == TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

This also works with character vectors:

```
sapply(c('AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN'), list)

$AAPL
[1] "AAPL"

$MSFT
[1] "MSFT"

$AMZN
[1] "AMZN"
```

Comment: The vector contains characters, for some reason using the above and similar code the resulting list ends up with all the elements in one component, i.e. can't create a list of 5000 elements.

Comment: Really? length(sapply(1:5000, list)) = 5000. And the elements are integers, not characters...

Comment: Sorry! I should have clarified.  My data is actually a dataframe of several thousand stock tickers.  I need a list whereby each stock ticker is an individual component of a list to be used to call additional data from an API.

Comment: Can you post a better example? This solution also works with characters, so it's a little unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Consider the following list:

Comment: x = list('AAPL,'TSLA)

Comment: print(x) [[1]] [1] 'AAPL' [[2]] [1] 'TSLA'

Comment: I have a data frame with 5000 stock tickers that I need in the above format. When I apply the listing functions, the results are always a list of length 1 format [1] 'AAPL' [2] 'TSLA' etc. with all the stock tickers in a single component of the list.

Comment: @Dan stop commenting on this answer and update your question with a little bit of sample data that reflects your actual use case. You've already got two answers that work for the example you shared. If they don't work for your real use case, you need to update your question (or accept one of these answers and ask a new question). We need to see what your data frame looks like (are the tickers in rows or columns?) and understand your input to help you get to your output.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be as:

```
x1 <- c(list(),1:5000)
str(x1)
# List of 10
# $ : int 1
# $ : int 2
# $ : int 3
# $ : int 4
# $ : int 5
# $ : int 6
# $ : int 7
# $ : int 8
#...
#.....
```

Answer (score 0):

`x1` is a one column data frame. Because a `data.frame` really is a `list` under the hood, `as.list()` just gives you a list of columns, in this case `list(x1$column1)`.

You need to run `as.list` on a *vector* to get the result you want. Either of these will work:

```
as.list(x1$your_column_name)
as.list(x1[["your_column_name"]])
```